# ruby form data receive

Tags: ruby, forms, parameters

Guy
this is just simple form in ruby

```
<%= form_tag("/page/create", method: "get") do %>
<% 5.times do %>
<%= text_field_tag :Name,(params[:Name]), size: 10 %><br>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag("send") %>
<% end%>
```

why in my control the `@Name=params['Name']` not work with me well ?

always not gives me any thing ?

Comment: You need to post your controller code. Too little information in your question. Also post the web server console output to see what the web server is receiving in the http request.

Comment: The console output showing the params would be most useful. also, you should do `@name` instead of `@Name` as that would be idiomatic ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You are posting the same paramter multiple times. This leads to an empty `params['Name']`, except you fill out the last of the input fields.

Most frameworks discard multiple parameters with the same name, using only the last one in the parameter list.

If you want to pass an array of fields to your controller, name your field with trailing open-close square brackets like this: `text_field_tag 'Name[]'`. This makes Rails populate `params['Name']` with an array of your input's values.

Note that `:Name[]` is not a valid Symbol in Ruby, so you'll have to use a String as the first argument to the `text_field_tag` helper.

Comment: when i tried to used [] like this 

<%= text_field_tag :Name[],(params[:Name]), size: 15  %>

its gives me error

Comment: thats why i didn't use a Symbol `:Name` but a String `'Name'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few things going on here:

Changing `<%= text_field_tag :Name,(params[:Name]), size: 10 %><br>` to `<%= text_field_tag :Name, size: 10 %><br>` might be the first step in moving forward.